# Can I pause a scroll function in selenium, scrape the current data, and then continue scrolling later in the script?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am a student working on a scraping project and I am having trouble completing my script because it fills my computer's memory with all of the data is stores.

It currently stores all of my data until the end, so my solution to this would be to break up the scrape into smaller bits and then write out the data periodically so it does not just continue to make one big list and then write out at the end.

In order to do this, I would need to stop my scroll method, scrape the loaded profiles, write out the data that I have collected, and then repeat this process without duplicating my data. It would be appreciated if someone could show me how to do this. Thank you for your help :)

Here's my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


Data = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://directory.bcsp.org/")
count = int(input("Number of Pages to Scrape: "))

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body") 
profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

while len(profile_count) < count:   # Get links up to "count"
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(1)
    profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

for link in profile_count:   # Calling up links
    temp = link.get_attribute('href')   # temp for
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")   # open new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # focus new tab
    driver.get(temp)

    # scrape code

    Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/div').text
    IssuedBy = "Board of Certified Safety Professionals"
    CertificationorDesignaationNumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[2]').text
    CertfiedorDesignatedSince = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[2]').text
    try:
        AccreditedBy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[2]/a').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        AccreditedBy = "N/A"

    try:
        Expires = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div[2]').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Expires = "N/A"

    info = Name, IssuedBy, CertificationorDesignaationNumber, CertfiedorDesignatedSince, AccreditedBy, Expires + "\n"

    Data.extend(info)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])


with open("Spredsheet.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(','.join(Data))

driver.close()
Test.py
Displaying Test.py.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach using **requests** and **beautifulsoup**. In the below script i have used the **API URL** fetched from website itself for ex:-[API URL](https://directory.bcsp.org/search_results.php?first_name=&last_name=&city=&state=&country=&unauthorized=0&retired=0&specialties=&industries=&certification=)

1. First it will create the URL(refer first url) for first iteration, add headers and data in .csv file.
2. Second iteration it will again create the URL(refer second url) with 2 extra params **start_on_page=20 & show_per_page=20** where **start_on_page** number 20 is incremented by 20 on each iteration and **show_per_page** = 100 defaulted to extract 100 records per iteration so on till all the data dumped in to the .csv file.[second iteration API URL](https://directory.bcsp.org/search_results.php?start_on_page=20&show_per_page=20&first_name=&last_name=&city=&state=&country=&certification=&unauthorized=0&retired=0&specialties=&industries=)
3. Script is dumping 4 things number, name, location and profile url.
4. On each iteration data will be appended to .csv file , so your memory issue will get resolved by this approach.

> Do not forget to add your system path in **file_path** variable where do you want to create **.csv** file before running the script.

```
   import requests
   from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
   requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
   import csv

   def scrap_directory_data():

    list_of_credentials = []
    file_path = ''
    file_name = 'credential_list.csv'
    count = 0
    page_number = 0
    page_size = 100
    create_url = ''

    main_url = 'https://directory.bcsp.org/search_results.php?'
    first_iteration_url = 'first_name=&last_name=&city=&state=&country=&certification=&unauthorized=0&retired=0&specialties=&industries='
    number_of_records = 0
    csv_headers = ['#','Name','Location','Profile URL']
    
    while True:
        if count == 0:
           create_url = main_url + first_iteration_url
           print('-' * 100)
           print('1 iteration URL created: ' + create_url)
           print('-' * 100)
        else:
            create_url = main_url + 'start_on_page=' + str(page_number) + '&show_per_page=' + str(page_size) + '&' + first_iteration_url
            print('-' * 100)
            print('Other then first iteration URL created: ' + create_url)
            print('-' * 100)
        page = requests.get(create_url,verify=False)
        extracted_text = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
        result = extracted_text.find_all('tr')
        if len(result) > 0:
            for idx, data in enumerate(result):
                if idx > 0:
                    number_of_records +=1
                    name = data.contents[1].text
                    location = data.contents[3].text
                    profile_url = data.contents[5].contents[0].attrs['href']
                    list_of_credentials.append({
                                    '#':number_of_records,
                                    'Name':name,
                                    'Location': location,
                                    'Profile URL': profile_url
                                            })
                print(data)
                with open(file_path + file_name ,'a+') as cred_CSV:
                    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(cred_CSV, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=csv_headers)                    
                    if idx == 0 and count == 0:
                        print('Writing CSV header now...')
                        csvwriter.writeheader()
                    else:
                        for item in list_of_credentials:
                            print('Writing data rows now..')
                            print(item)
                            csvwriter.writerow(item)
                            list_of_credentials = []
        count +=1
        page_number +=20

    scrap_directory_data()
```